# ZfcUser login with IP Address [Zend Framework 2]

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am using **zfcuser** want to login with IP Address instead of asking user for password, IP's are stored in DB and user need to enter his/her username/email for authentication, IP is retrieved from db using **authenticate.pre** event My Code is :

$this->listeners[] = $sharedManager->attach('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain', 'authenticate.pre', array($this, 'LoginIp'));

**LoginIp** method is:

```
  public function loginIp(Event $e) {  

    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

    //Get user from DB

    $user = $em->getRepository('LcUser\Entity\User')
            ->findOneBy(array('email' => $_POST['identity']));

    //Get IP Address from Group 

    $group = $em->getRepository('LcGroup\Entity\Group')
            ->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getGroup()));


    //Check if IP of organization and current machine is same, 
    //Set authentication with username from user and password from DB

       if($group->getIpAddresses()==$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']){              
             $_POST['credential']=$user->getUnhashedPassword();                  
       }
 }
```

**Question**
I am updating the $_POST['credential'] value by assigning it new value from DB but zfcuser doesn't process this instead it process the old value which is coming by submitting login form? I need help in figuring it out how to update the login credential in order to login user with IP and username and without password?

Answer (score 0):

However a public IP address is unique you cannot use it to uniquely identify your users (or clients). In case users are on a network using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (for example your  your office network) they share one single public IP address.

With your solution those users (who are requesting your website from within the same network) will be sharing the same authenticated identity. This is most likely not what you want.

Check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/148664/how-and-why-all-devices-in-your-home-share-one-ip-address/) or [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/195323/do-two-computers-on-the-same-wi-fi-network-have-the-same-ip-address/) or [other pages on Google](https://www.google.se/webhp#q=do+compters+have+a+unique+ip+address) for more information on this topic.

**Note:** *A MAC address was supposed to be uniquely identifying clients (devices) but [the concept of unique MAC addresses has proven to fail](http://www.howtogeek.com/228286/how-is-the-uniqueness-of-mac-addresses-enforced/) and a MAC addresses can also easily be spoofed (faked) by others so I would not suggest using that solution either. I would suggest to stick to a more conventional solution.*

Comment: Wilt you are right, but I am dealing with this situation, I am asking for username, which belongs to a specific group, and group has IP address stored in DB. So instead of asking password which is stored in db, I am asking for username and IP. Thanks

Comment: @ZahoorAhmad And what if users use the same name!?

Comment: the username/email is unique in zfcuser. Users with unique email/username is already created just want to login them with predefined IP with their username.